# How to write Xpath expressions to distinguish between results?

Tags: xpath

I am new to xpath expression. Need help on a issue
    Consider the following Document :

```
<tbody><tr>
<td>By <strong>Bec</strong></td>
<td><strong>Great Support</strong></td>
</tr></tbody>
```

In this I have to find the text inside  tags separately.

Following is my xpath expression:

```
//tbody//td//strong/text();
```

It evaluates output as expected:

```
Bec
Great Support
```

How can I write xpath expressions to distinguish between the results i.e `Bec`and `Great Support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather unclear what you're trying to do, but the following should succeed in selecting them separately:

```
//tbody/tr/td[1]/strong
```

and

```
//tbody/tr/td[2]/strong
```

Note that the `text()` you had at the end is most likely not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you're looking for... anyway, assuming you're asking to retrieve a node based on its text you can look up for text content by doing something like:

```
//tbody//td//strong/text()[.="Bec"]
```

PS

in `[.=""]` the dot is an alias for <del>`text()`</del> `self::node()` (thanks JLRishe for pointing out the mistake).

Comment: `.` is an alias for `self::node()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand 100%, but if you're trying to get the text of the first and the second strong tags, you can use position (1 based index)

```
//tbody/td[position()=1]/strong/text() //first text

//tbody/td[position()=2]/strong/text() //second text
```

This solution only applies to the current sample though, where your strong tags are inside either the first or second td tag.